# Web scraping with beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, function, loops, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get some information from the website Truecar but with my code, each time it wants to get the information from next page, it repeats scraping page 1.How can I scrape multiple pages without the first page being repeated with beautifulsoup?
thanks

```
carname=input('Please enter the name of car: ')
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import mysql.connector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager 
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',host='127.0.0.1',database='info',password='nooshika')
cursor=cnx.cursor()
listname=[]
listprice=[]
listtmile=[]
listyearmodel=[]
list2=[]
final_list=[]
#response=requests.get('https://www.truecar.com/used-cars-for-sale/listings/?page=1')
#soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
def scrape(response,soup):
    for link in soup.find_all('span',class_="truncate"):
        link=link.get_text()
        link=re.sub(r'Excellent Price',' ',str(link))
        listname.append(link)
    for j in listname:
        if j==' ':
            listname.remove(j)
    for i in soup.find_all('div',class_="truncate text-xs",attrs={'data-test':"vehicleMileage"}):
        listtmile.append(i.get_text())
    for k in soup.find_all('span',attrs={'data-test':"vehicleListingPriceAmount"}):
        k=k.get_text()
        listprice.append(k)
    for l in soup.find_all('span',class_="vehicle-card-year text-xs"):
        l=l.get_text()
        listyearmodel.append(l)
    for k,i2 in enumerate(listname):
        for k1,i3 in enumerate(listprice):
            for k2,i4 in enumerate(listtmile):
                for k3,i5 in enumerate(listyearmodel):
                    if k==k1==k2==k3:
                        list2.append((i5,i2,i3,i4))

pages = list(range(1,3))
for count in pages:
    response=requests.get('https://www.truecar.com/used-cars-for-sale/listings/?page={}'.format(count))
    soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')  
    scrape(response,soup)




def contains_carname(a):
    return isinstance(a, str) and carname in a
matches = [x for x in list2 if contains_carname(x[1])]
while matches==[]:
    matches = [x for x in list2 if contains_carname(x[1])]
    if matches!=[]:
        break
    print('No match.Please enter again')
    carname=input('Please enter the name of car: ')    
print(matches)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current implementation, you're appending data to lists outside the loop that scrapes each page. This leads to the accumulation of data from previous pages every time a new page is scraped. To fix this issue, you should clear your lists before scraping each new page.
Try using this:

```
# ... (your import statements and database connection)

carname = input('Please enter the name of the car: ')

# ... (your list initialization and functions)

pages = list(range(1, 3))
for count in pages:
    response = requests.get('https://www.truecar.com/used-cars-for-sale/listings/?page={}'.format(count))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    # Clear lists before scraping each page
    listname.clear()
    listprice.clear()
    listtmile.clear()
    listyearmodel.clear()
    
    scrape(response, soup)

# ... (your matching and printing code)
```

By calling the clear() method on your lists before scraping each page, you ensure that you're starting with empty lists for each page and prevent accumulation of data from previous pages.